# Alternatives to "OR" in where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, query-performance

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT  ordIdent.Identifier, ord.OrderId
FROM    OrderIdentifier ordIdent
        JOIN [order] ord
            ON ordIdent.OrderId = ord.OrderId
WHERE   ordIdent.Identifier = '29584'
        OR ord.ClientOrderId = '29584'
```

The idea is that we are searching using the value *'29584'* and we don't really know if it is a `ClientOrderId` or an `Identifier`, so we want to search both.

This gives really really bad performance.  It pulls millions of rows (125 thousand from one and 20 Million from the other)

But this query:

```
SELECT  ordIdent.Identifier, ord.OrderId
FROM    OrderIdentifier ordIdent
        JOIN [order] ord
            ON ordIdent.OrderId = ord.OrderId
WHERE   ord.ClientOrderId = '01193504' 

UNION

SELECT  ordIdent.Identifier, ord.OrderId
FROM    OrderIdentifier ordIdent
        JOIN [order] ord
            ON ordIdent.OrderId = ord.OrderId
WHERE   ordIdent.Identifier = '01193504'
```

has good performance.  Normally I would just do this and call it a day.

But my actual query is very large, and I would rather not call it twice (though it is still better than using the "or".)  So before I just set it up to be called twice, I thought I would ask around and see if I have other options.

It seems I should be to do some kind of left join to make this work.  But I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

**Is there a way to do this in one query that has a left join instead of an "OR"?**  (Or some other kind of option?)

**UPDATE:**
OK, I got thinking about it and I realized I could just factor out the OR into a CTE that uses the `union` and then use the CTE the actual query.

I will leave this open in case there is a better way to deal with it, but a CTE fixes my issue.

Comment: I left it as `union` because I can't be sure that there will not be duplicates.  (I my real system it is possible that both the `Identifier` and the `ClientOrderId` are the same.)

Comment: You might try:  WHERE '29584' IN (ordIdent.Identifier, ord.ClientOrderId). I wouldn't expect too much, but the rewrite should be easy to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can rewrite that query to use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT  ordIdent.Identifier, ord.OrderId
FROM    OrderIdentifier ordIdent
        FULL OUTER JOIN [order] ord
            ON ordIdent.OrderId = ord.OrderId
            AND ( ordIdent.Identifier = '29584'
                    OR ord.ClientOrderId = '29584')
WHERE ordIdent.Identifier IS NOT NULL AND ord.OrderId IS NOT NULL;
```

But why would you want to? You'll end up reading all rows from both tables with that syntax which causes the performance problem that you're trying to avoid. `UNION` or `UNION ALL` is the right way to go here. For filters like you have you can still use `UNION ALL` like so:

```
SELECT  ordIdent.Identifier, ord.OrderId
FROM    OrderIdentifier ordIdent
        JOIN [order] ord
            ON ordIdent.OrderId = ord.OrderId
WHERE   ord.ClientOrderId = '01193504' 

UNION

SELECT  ordIdent.Identifier, ord.OrderId
FROM    OrderIdentifier ordIdent
        JOIN [order] ord
            ON ordIdent.OrderId = ord.OrderId
WHERE   ordIdent.Identifier = '01193504' AND (ord.ClientOrderId 
 IS NULL OR ord.ClientOrderId <> '01193504')
```

Sometimes there's a slight performance benefit in doing so. It depends on your data.